# When does React re-render components?

Tags: reactjs

When looking into React's render performance, there are a few terms and concepts that can be hard to understand. It wasn't 100% clear to me what a VDOM was or how React decides to re-render components for quite some time.

When looking into React's render performance, there are a few terms and concepts that can be hard to understand. It wasn't 100% clear to me what a VDOM was or how React decides to re-render components for quite some time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there are insufficient details. I'm voting to close this question because there are insufficient details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into React lifecycle. It's crucial to understand and it will determine how you code your apps. I cannot stress this enough, as you will be making mistakes down the line.

In general, after initial render, components re-render when their state changes. But there is a lot more to it. This a good starting point: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

This is also a great visual overview that helped me a lot: https://github.com/Wavez/react-hooks-lifecycle